Characterizing the Result of Lift and Project Method for Integer Programming
I have the following integer linear programming problem:

Let $P=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\colon Ax\geq b\}\subseteq [0,1]^n$ be a polytope. For a fixed index $j\in [n]$, consider the polyhedron $P^j$ obtained by the lift and project method in the $j$-th variable. That is, $P^j$ is the projection into $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the linearization of the system $x_j(Ax-b)\geq 0$, $(1-x_j)(Ax-b)\geq 0$. Prove that
$$P^j = \text{conv}(\{x\in P \colon x_j=0\}\cup \{x\in P\colon x_j =1\})$$

I've managed to prove $P^j \supseteq \text{conv}(\{x\in P \colon x_j=0\}\cup \{x\in P\colon x_j =1\})$ by simply observing that $\{x\in P \colon x_j=0\}\cup \{x\in P\colon x_j =1\}\subseteq P^j$ (since any point in this set satisfies $x_j(Ax-b)\geq 0$ and $(1-x_j)(Ax-b)\geq 0$ and, a fortiori satisfies the projection onto any subspace) and taking convex combination on both sides (the RHS being already convex). I can't really prove $P^j \subseteq \text{conv}(\{x\in P \colon x_j=0\}\cup \{x\in P\colon x_j =1\})$ since I don't really know how to characterize this set in a manageable way.
How do I prove $P^j \subseteq \text{conv}(\{x\in P \colon x_j=0\}\cup \{x\in P\colon x_j =1\})$?

This is Theorem 3.12 in Optimization over Integers by Bertsimas and Weismantel.
